# EntityWrapper error in in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I"m getting following error on checkout page after applying userpoints_discount in drupal commerce.

Error:
having error at EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property commerce_product. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 335 \sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc

Can you please help me in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

-Naveed

Comment: As mentioned previously, please report all bugs to the relevant module issue queue on Drupal.org.